# how to perform the action form after the recaptcha

Tags: php, forms, recaptcha

i want to post a comment using my form, it works without a recaptcha but when i add the recaptcha it doesn't work here is my code with recaptcha

```
<?php
           echo "<form class='recaptchaForm' method='POST' action='".setComments($conn)."'>
              <input type='hidden' name='room_name' value='$name'>
              <input type='hidden' name='date' value='".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."'>
              <input type='text' name='uname' id='uname' class='name' placeholder='Name' required  /><br>
              <input type='text' name='umail'
              id='umail' class='name' placeholder='E-mail' required  />

              <textarea id='message' class='message' name='message'
              placeholder='Join the Discussion'
              required ></textarea><br>

              <div class='g-recaptcha' data-sitekey='6LfF4XYUAAAAAMaLkn2-AMUsoEkt-ym-SFsCVEBG'></div>

              <button type='submit' id='post' name='commentSubmit'>Post Review</button>

            </form>";
        ?>
```

here is the script

```
<script>
    $(document).on('click', '[name="commentSubmit"]' function(event)  {

    var recaptcha = $('[name="g-recaptcha-response"]').val();
    if(recaptcha===""){

    event.preventDefault();
    alert("Please Check Recaptcha");
 }
  event.preventDefault();
   $.post("submit.php",{
   "secret":"6LfF4XYUAAAAAFXOxblX4Vttp67bmaRJXkua6Ks-",
   "response":recaptcha
 },function(response){
 console.log(response);

 $('.recaptchaForm').submit();

   }); // End of response

 }); // End of $.post
}); // End of click event function
</script>
```

here is the submit.php

```
<?php
   $secret = $_POST["secret"];
   $response = $_POST["response"];
   $url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify? 
   secret=".$secret."&response=".$response;
   $verify = file_get_contents($url);
   echo $verify;
?>
```

here is the action='".setComments($conn)."'

```
function setComments($conn){
    if(isset($_POST['commentSubmit'])){
        $room_name = $_POST['room_name'];
        $date = $_POST['date'];
        $uname = $_POST['uname'];
        $umail = $_POST['umail'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];

        $query = "insert into comments_table (cname, cmail, cmessage,room_name,cdate) Values ('$uname','$umail','$message','$room_name','$date')";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    }
    }
```

i think i missing something but i dont know what it is
please help me im a beginner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think event.preventDefault is not letting the form to submit. So check by modifying the script to this :

```
$(document).on('click', '[name="commentSubmit"]', function(event)  {
event.preventDefault();
var recaptcha = $('[name="g-recaptcha-response"]').val();
if(recaptcha===""){

  alert("Please Check Recaptcha");

}
else{

 $.post("submit.php",{
    "secret":"6LfF4XYUAAAAAFXOxblX4Vttp67bmaRJXkua6Ks-",
    "response":recaptcha
 },function(response){
    console.log(response);

    $('.recaptchaForm').submit();


   });
 }

 });
```

Comment: Santu roy nothing happen

Comment: @KenVerganio I have edited the answer, please check once

Comment: the form submitted but when the captcha is not verify or not check , the form also submitted, it should display "Please check captcha"

Comment: there are two conditions where the form should not be submitted, first is when the recaptcha value is empty and the second one is after the ajax call if the captcha is mismatched. so can you tell me in which condition the form is getting submitted?if its for the second condition then please provide an example of the response you are getting in the console

Comment: Theres no error in console about the two condition you mention. the error that show is "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" this. And i dont know where to put the missing parentheses

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
recaptcha__en.js:89 [Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'touchstart' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5745543795965952

Comment: You need to close the $post parenthesis. So add another }) after function (response) close

Comment: i did what you told but it display the same error, can you edit your answer so i can understand it completely, this is what i added "function(response)})"

Comment: i copy paste your edited answer and remove all the comment but it display the same error

Comment: Please give screenshot of the error that you are getting.

Comment: "http://alar-regulations.000webhostapp.com/here.PNG" here is the screenshot

Comment: Edit your post with the updated code, so that I can review it

Comment: i edited  my post please check it and the only thing that change is the script and here is the website that im working on check it if you want to "http://alar-regulations.000webhostapp.com/room.php?name=Mahogany%20Room%201"

Comment: I have edited my code, It will remove the console error.

Comment: it works and remove and the console error message but when the captcha is verify it also not save the message into database and diplay in website

Comment: code edited. you need to put the $.post on else condition.

Comment: it didnt save and display the comment and the captcha is looping in the console

Comment: why it doesnt work on me lol and how are you can comment but i cant, i put the code you edited and looping is gone but it didnt save my comment when verified

Comment: as I couldn't make the connection with DB, so now it is difficult for me to debug the last step

Comment: i can give you the access how can i pm you

Comment: I have sent you a request on fb